# Slice of known compile-time size to array, infallibly

Tags: arrays, rust, slice

```rust
let some_datagram [u8; 8] = [0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00];
let a : &[u8; 2] = some_datagram[0..2];
let b : &[u8; 4] = some_datagram[2..6];
let c : &[u8; 2] = some_datagram[6..8];
```

The above will not work, because `some_datagram[0..2]` is `&[u8]`, not `&[u8; 2]`. This makes perfect sense when using other types of `Range*`, where the start/end points are not known at compile time. I know that there's an implementation of `TryInto` for `&[u8]` into `&[u8; n]` but since this is all known at compile time it bothers me to have to deal with the error case that I know can't happen.

Is there an alternative method besides `[]` that returns a fixed size array? Possibly a standard macro?

Comment: *"it bothers me to have to deal with the error case that I know can't happen"*. That's what `.unwrap` and `.expect` are for. Shy of the compiler having inconsistent rules for when conversions are allowed, there isn't really any other way to express this.

Comment: @Brian "there isn't really any other way to express this", well there is but it's super ugly. `&[some_datagram[0], some_datagram[1]]` is `&[u8; 2]` - but it'd be nice if the language gave you some syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 1):

The [`array_macro`](https://docs.rs/array-macro/1.0.4/array_macro/macro.array.html) crate exports the macro `array!` which allows for the construction of arrays using a callback over the indices of the new array. The documentation illustrates this with following example:

```
assert_eq!(array![|x| x; 3], [0, 1, 2]);
```

In your case, you could accomplish the slice to array conversion with the statements

```
let a : &[u8; 2] = array![|i| some_datagram[i    ]; 2];
let b : &[u8; 4] = array![|i| some_datagram[i + 2]; 4];
let c : &[u8; 2] = array![|i| some_datagram[i + 6]; 2];
```

Whether this is more or less readable than using the standard `TryInto` implementation and `.unwrap` is a matter of opinion. Since this is a third party crate, you'll also want to factor in the fact that most developers reading this code won't necessarily be familiar with what the `array!` macro does.

Comment: Upvoted because it's an answer that technically works, but for the reasons you mentioned I'll pass. Unfortunately in practice I need `[u8; 44]`, which is just beyond what `TryInto` will support (for now).

Comment: Ended up finding the [arrayref](https://docs.rs/arrayref/0.3.6/arrayref/) crate, which has an `array_ref!(array, start, end)` macro. Until `rustc` grows the ability to do it natively, this will do.